# Passing information between panels and classes

Tags: c#

My application (namespace) has a master form (Form) that contains a panel (panel).

When the master form loads, it calls a subform into it's panel. That subform acts as a splash page. It has a "launch" button on it. When the button is clicked, the subform should hide and a new form should load into the panel.

```
    private void buttonLaunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Hub NewHub = new Hub();
        NewHub.TopLevel = false;
        NewHub.AutoScroll = true;
        Master.panelMaster.Controls.Clear();
        Master.panelMaster.Controls.Add(NewHub);
        NewHub.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        NewHub.Show();
    }
```

I'm getting the error:

> Error  1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Manager_0._2.Master.panelMaster'

I'm not sure how to interpret the error to resolve the issue.

Comment: I haven't finished reading the question yet, mostly due to getting confused by your capitalization.  Recommended reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, assuming you have a class called `namespace.class` that contains a member named `panel`, the compiler is telling you that you seem to be trying to access `panel` via the class itself rather than an instance of the class (i.e. an object).  To make an instance of `class`, do something like this:

```
namespace.class c = new namespace.class();
```

Then you can access the property or field named `panel` on that object:

```
c.panel.Controls.Clear();
```

Note: your naming choices are very poor.  Calling a namespace `namespace` or a class `class` is just asking for trouble.  Here are some recommended naming conventions:

[Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Update:** from a closer read of your question, it appears that you're trying to add a `Form` to a `Panel`.  Once you get past this compilation issue, you're going to start getting runtime errors, because that's just not how Windows Forms works.  You can't put a `Form` in a `Panel`.  `Forms` are top-level UI elements.  I honestly don't understand your goals here well enough to suggest what to do instead.

Comment: I had named things as I did trying to make the post more clear. I've edited the post to reflect to names ive used. 

The application will have multiple forms that purposes. Instead of opening several different windows, the idea was that you would have a cluster of buttons on the side of the main form, outside of the panel. You would use those buttons to call the forms you need to interact with. cleans up the UI and doesnt clutter the desktop. 

does that help you understand the overall goal?

Comment: It does.  But again, `Forms` are top-level UI elements and can't be contained in `Panels`.  You could use custom controls (inheriting directly from `Control`, or from `UserControl` if you want to edit them in the Windows Forms Designer).  But you can't use `Forms`.

Comment: About naming, the real versions you've edited into your question are better than the fake ones you used at first.  In particular, there's an important difference between instantiating a `Hub` (presumably a subclass of `Form` with custom design and logic) and instantiating a generic `Form`.  I couldn't understand why you'd be making an empty `Form` and trying to display it.  FYI, it's also recommended to name local variables with `camelCasing` rather than `PascalCasing` so they are easily distinguished from class and public/protected property names.